# newVal and oldVal always the same when watching for Pinia state changes

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

For some reason, when watching for Pinia state changes, the `newVal` and `oldVal` in the watch function are always identical (except for the very first time).

This is how my code looks like:

```
const { searchFilters } = storeToRefs(searchFiltersStore)

watch(searchFilters.value.categories, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if (
    newVal.length !== oldVal.length ||
    newVal.every((value, index) => value !== oldVal[index])
  ) {
    reset(undefined, true)
  }
}, { deep: true })
```

`searchFilters.value.categories` are string[] (array made of strings) type and initially is an empty array.

When the first change is triggered, the `oldVal` is an empty array and the `newVal` is whatever it supposed to be.
But after that, every new trigger has `oldVal` the same as `newVal` therefore, my if statement is never valid.

What am I missing?

Comment: This behavior is documented, see https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example "Note: `newValue` will be equal to `oldValue` here [on nested watchers] because they both point to the same object!" - still figuring out how to get around this

Answer (score 0):

I found that in order to watch an array, you have to pass a copy of the array and not the existing array like so:

```
watch(() => [...searchFilters.value.categories], (newVal, oldVal) => {
      ...
});
```

Also, the `deep` parameter in my case was not necessary.